# How can I add a vertical scrollbar to my div automatically?

Tags: css, html, scrollbar, overflow

I want to add a vertical scrollbar to my `<div>`. I've tried `overflow: auto`, but it is not working. I've tested my code in Firefox and Chrome.

I'm pasting the div style code here:

```
float: left;
width: 1000px;
overflow: auto;
```

Comment: a jsfiddle or more css with your markup

Comment: Try this: `overflow-y:scroll` and some **height**. Go through this [**docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).

Comment: Thanks Mr_Green for your reply. But this code is not working for me.

Comment: To make the Scroll work, the inside content should **overflow**.

Comment: Post your html and css code here.

Comment: if you have a display of `flex`, then this will not work. I also had same problem, and tried all the possible overflows, heights and the element's properties, but none worked! At last I fixed that from changing the `display: flex` to `display: block`

Answer (score 192):

You need to assign some height to make the `overflow: auto;` property work.

For testing purpose, add `height: 100px;` and check.

and also it will be better if you give `overflow-y:auto;` instead of `overflow: auto;`, because this makes the element to scroll only vertical but not horizontal.

```
float:left;
width:1000px;
overflow-y: auto;
height: 100px;
```

If you don't know the height of the container and you want to show vertical scrollbar when the container reaches a fixed height say `100px`, use `max-height` instead of `height` property.

For more information, read this [**MDN article**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).

Comment: Yes i got your point and tested, it's works fine in Chrome but not in FireFox. One more confusing thing is the vertical Scrollbar is appearing on Page load time in FF but disappeared when page loading is completed!

Comment: "You need to assign some height" exactly my problem, thanks! :P

Answer (score 67):

You have to add `max-height` property.

```css
.ScrollStyle
{
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="ScrollStyle">
  Scrollbar Test!<br/>
  Scrollbar Test!<br/>
  Scrollbar Test!<br/>
  Scrollbar Test!<br/>
  Scrollbar Test!<br/>
  Scrollbar Test!<br/>
  Scrollbar Test!<br/>
  Scrollbar Test!<br/>
  Scrollbar Test!<br/>
  Scrollbar Test!<br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18):

I got an amazing scroller on my `div-popup`. To apply, add this style to your div element:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
height: XXXpx;
```

The `height` you specify will be the height of the div and once if you have contents to exceed this height, you have to scroll it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

To show vertical scroll bar in your div you need to add

```
height: 100px;   
overflow-y : scroll;
```

or

```
height: 100px; 
overflow-y : auto;
```

Answer (score 10):

I'm not quite sure what you're attempting to use the div for, but this is an example with some random text.

Mr_Green gave the correct instructions when he said to add `overflow-y: auto` as that restricts it to vertical scrolling. This is a JSFiddle example:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MitulP91/xEy9E/3/)

Comment: First of all @Mr_Green your suggestion is working fine in Chrome but not in FF. And is there any alternative of adding Height, because i can't add Height to my Div for my design structure.

Answer (score 4):

Since OS X Lion, the scrollbar on websites are hidden by default and only visible once you start scrolling. Personally, I prefer the hidden scrollbar, but in case you really need it, you can overwrite the default and force the scrollbar in WebKit browsers back like this:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 7px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer

Comment: the source (and explanation) seems to be: http://simurai.com/blog/2011/07/26/webkit-scrollbar .

Answer (score 0):

**In My case**

Scroll vertically automatically

```
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
```