# CSS - Vertical scrolling to list of ULs

Tags: jquery, html, css

Have created a `select` box using `UL` and `LI`s. Now wanted to add verticle scrollbar for the list. So followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183296/how-can-i-add-a-vertical-scrollbar-to-my-div-automatically) and some more stackoverflow queries. From that I conclude that I would need to use:

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

But no luck.
I have to add scrollbar if there are more than 5 items visible. Have a look at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jks0e2zy/3/)

Comment: You need to specify an height/max-height in order to get any content overflowing

Comment: @A.Wolff - I tried specify height but it is showing selectbox visible always with a scrollbar.

Comment: @A.Wolff - Great! Thanks, Worked, like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you expect like this.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jks0e2zy/4/

```
    .select {
cursor:pointer;
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
font:normal 11px/22px Arial, Sans-Serif;
color:black;
border:1px solid #ccc;
min-width:20%;
font-weight: bold;
height: 150px;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it shows box visible even though all inner items are hidden.