# CSS - Added indentation is not working for nested ul li

Tags: html, css

I'm newbie to CSS, I want to add some extra spacing to the  `ul` -`li`s which have parent `ul.optiongroup`. But those `ul.optiongroup` can also contain more `ul.optiongroup`s and `li`s. So. Here is the html look like [[Pl.see my old query for reference if required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33390231/css-vertical-scrolling-to-list-of-uls)] and the  [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jks0e2zy/8/):

**NESTED UL-LIs**:

```
<div id="target" class="treeselector">
  <div class="styledSelect">
    Select
  </div>
  <ul class="optiongroup expand" rel="Home">
    <li class="title">
      <span>&nbsp;</span>Home
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="optiongroup expand" rel="Products">
    <li class="title">
      <span class="fa fa-minus-square-o">&nbsp;</span>Products
    </li>
    <li rel="PCPROducts1" class="expand">
      PCPROducts1
    </li>
    <li rel="PCPROducts5" class="expand">
      PCPROducts5
    </li>
    <ul class="optiongroup expand" rel="PCPROducts6">
      <li class="title">
        <span class="fa fa-plus-square-o">&nbsp;</span>PCPROducts6
      </li>
      <ul class="optiongroup" rel="6th Product">
        <li class="title">
          <span class="fa fa-plus-square-o">&nbsp;</span>6th Product
        </li>
        <li rel="Digital">
          Digital
        </li>
        <li rel="Analog">
          Analog
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Tried to add CSS like this:

```
.optiongroup li{
  margin-left:40px;
  border:  1px red solid; /* Just to see what's happening there */
}
```

- How can I achieve this?
- What's the easiest way to design `ul` -`li` with minimum css here.

Comment: You need to start using more specific (and sometimes more detailed selectors).

Comment: [**The 30 CSS Selectors you Must Memorize**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

Comment: <UL> must not contain any elements other than <LI>. When you are nesting lists, you must place your nested <ul></ul> inside an <li>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a lot of UL tags when its not needed.

You could try doing something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Aliquam</li>
  <li>
      <ul>
          <li>Lorem ipsum .</li>
          <li>Aliquam tincidunt</li>
          <li>Vestibulum</li>
      </ul>  
  </li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Aliquam tincidunt</li>
</ul>
```

Notice that second UL is inside the LI

Comment: Whilst true...this does not answer the OPs question.

Comment: @Paulie_D I guess, one of the reasons I suggested this is because by default it will add indentation to the sub level UL. which is what I think OP wanted.